# Can I create this shape with CSS only?

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

I'm building a hero section for a webpage that has a particular shape, at the moment I'm just using an image as an overlay for the actual section background, but I'm looking to reduce the amount of requests I make and would like to know if the following shape can be done using CSS:

[image]

So the black part is where the actual image goes, while the white section is what I'm trying to build using CSS;

Comment: yes it's possible ...

Comment: @TemaniAfif I don't think so.

Comment: i wanted to possibly give you a start, 

<p id="rcorners1">Rounded corners!</p>
#rcorners1 {
  border-radius: 25px;
  background: #73AD21;
  padding: 20px; 
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px; 
}

also this may help - https://css-tricks.com/books/volume-i/make-heart-shape/

Comment: Can I get a suggestion on what to look into? I'm searching for rounded corners or gradients, but I'm not sure what would be the best approach, using a bunch of absolute `divs` to build the shape doesn't sound right

Comment: @aaronlilly alright, I'll give it a try like that, thank you for the tip

Comment: @dgknca you are challenging me? :)

Comment: As @TemaniAfif says, it's possible and whenever there is question like this, I post this site: https://bennettfeely.com/clippy/

Comment: @TemaniAfif yes, exactly :)

Comment: I would personally use an SVG as a background image

Comment: Well, using it as a background image wouldn't save a request, but inline SVG would be what I go for.

Comment: @JacqueGoupil There's pros and cons for all SVG inclusion method. Inline will make the browser parse the SVG for each occurence. SVG in `src` attribute of an img tag may optimise the render, but will still create a DOM node. `background-image` might be the best solution depending on the number of occurences of the SVG.

Comment: @Seblor that's good to know, for this particular case I'm thinking on using it in two sections at most, so maybe it wouldn't be too much of an issue

Comment: @IvanS95 In that case you could indeed use an inline SVG without any performance issue. Also using inline SVG lets you have a better handle of the hitboxes, and allows you to create any kind of shape.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is an idea with one element and `radial-gradient` to approximate it

```css
.box {
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  display:inline-block;
  overflow:hidden;
  position:relative;
}
.box:before,
.box:after{
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:50%;
  bottom:0;
  background:
    radial-gradient(100% 116.3% at top   right, transparent 99%,#fff 100%) top,
    radial-gradient(100% 116.3% at bottom left, #fff 99%,transparent 100%) bottom;
  background-size:100% 50%;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
.box:after {
  right:0;
  left:50%;
  transform:scaleX(-1);
}

body {
  background:linear-gradient(to right, purple, blue);
}
```

```html
<div class="box">

</div>
```

You can then adjust left/right/bottom properties to control the overal shape by having some oveflow and overlap:

```css
.box {
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  display:inline-block;
  overflow:hidden;
  position:relative;
}
.box:before,
.box:after{
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:-2px;
  right:40%;
  bottom:-45%;
  background:
    radial-gradient(100% 116.3% at top   right, transparent 99%,#fff 100%) top,
    radial-gradient(100% 116.3% at bottom left, #fff 99%,transparent 100%) bottom;
  background-size:100% 50%;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
.box:after {
  right:-2px;
  left:40%;
  transform:scaleX(-1);
}

body {
  background:linear-gradient(to right, purple, blue);
}
```

```html
<div class="box">

</div>
```

---

Here is an idea using SVG to replace the `radial-gradient`:

```css
.box {
  height: 200px;
  overflow:hidden;
  position:relative;
}
.box:before,
.box:after{
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:50%;
  bottom:0;
  background:url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 64 64" preserveAspectRatio="none"><path fill="white" d="M64 64 C56 30 8 48 0 0 L0 64 Z"/></svg>');
  background-size:100% 100%;
}
.box:after {
  right:0;
  left:50%;
  transform:scaleX(-1);
}

body {
  background:linear-gradient(to right, purple, blue);
}
```

```html
<div class="box">

</div>
```

Here is a good online tool to edit the SVG: http://jxnblk.com/paths/. Simply append the path to the url at the end and edit it;

```
http://jxnblk.com/paths/?d=M64 64 C56 30 8 48 0 0 L0 64 Z
```

Comment: @JacqueGoupil I'll try building the SVG to do it like that, but this is impressive really, will see which one is better for me

Comment: @dgknca change the coloration of the gradients (even the transparent) and you will clearly indentify the trick ;)

Comment: One thing that I notice, which I suppose an SVG would be a bit better for, is the 'border' of the gradients right? since using 100% for the white section won't create a good-looking curve

Comment: @IvanS95 yes, this won't be perfect but you can always adjust the different value to make it better .. instead of the 99%, you can for example use 99.5%. I will also add my SVG version later ;)