# Creating slope-shaped div using css

Tags: css

[image: Slope]

Simple enough question: Is it possible to replicate the above shape using CSS only? I'm not looking for someone to do the job for me,but I can't find an approach yet of how (or whether) it could be done.

Comment: almost like this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/51086086/8620333

Comment: also this https://stackoverflow.com/a/56565969/8620333 if you do a rotation of the first snippet

Comment: sorry and many thanks for pointing me in the right direction

Comment: sorry and many thanks for pointing me in the right direction